# Download dynamically created Flash

Tags: download, flash

Is there a way to download dynamically created Flash (SWF) files? I'd like to fetch them and convert to PNG. (This can be done for example with swfrender.)

For example, when pointing my webbrowser to http://flashserver.company.com/statsgraph.jsp?data=2012-04 (URL completely made up), a JSP script on that server creates a statistics graph. But this is done on-the-fly, so there's no SWF **file** that I could download (for example with wget).

I could take a screen shot from what my browser displays, but I prefer to do this automatically with a **server-side** (shell or PHP) script, because it's about a few dozen graphs to be downloaded, once per month. BWT, what I intend to do is fully legal. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely and overly complicated to render SWFs server side. The SWF probably holds no data itself, anyway, it probably just displays it.

You need to use Firebug or something similar to dig up the SWFs data source and save that data set instead of the SWF. Then, you can create your own image graph from that data set, using [jpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/) or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my suspicion that retrieving dynamically created SWF is pretty cumbersome. Thanks for pointing out jpGraph; I'll give that a try.